# Stripe Token is not created in the stripe server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am creating a rails app with Stripe. I can only use the [standalone accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts#standalone-accounts) because Managed Accounts are not available in France. I use [shared customers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers) because people earning money on my app are sharing their customers.

[Create Card Token doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token)

Of course, What I am showing to you uses my Test Stripe environment.

To charge a customer to a user, I create a token :

```
tok = Stripe::Token.create(
  {:customer => customer.id, :card => customer.cards.last.stripe_id},
  {:stripe_account => user.stripe_user_id}
)
=> #<Stripe::Token:0x3fd9c3830900 id=tok_19fYblIUbyeToO5BfgwmLR9Y> JSON: {
  "id": "tok_19fYblIUbyeToO5BfgwmLR9Y",
  "object": "token",
  "card":     {"id":"card_19fYblIUbyeToO5BwRTTlJ1x","object":"card","address_city":null,"address_country":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_line2":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_zip_check":null,"brand":"Visa","country":"US","cvc_check":"pass","dynamic_last4":null,"exp_month":12,"exp_year":2020,"fingerprint":"xxsPLKbXK7swE7It","funding":"credit","last4":"4242","metadata":{},"name":null,"tokenization_method":null},
  "client_ip": "31.33.230.61",
  "created": 1485280889,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

After that, I want to charge the customer using that token but unfortunately, the token doesn't exist on Stripe Servers:

```
Stripe::Token.retrieve(tok.id)
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: No such token: tok_19fYk2IUbyeToO5Bo4thhjn7
 from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/stripe-1.58.0/lib/stripe.rb:326:in `handle_api_error'
```

When I try to charge the customer or save the token as a customer source, it gives me the same error.
I tried to create a basic charge to see if it was an error from a larger scale:

```
tok = Stripe::Token.create(
  :card => {
    :number => "4242424242424242",
    :exp_month => 1,
    :exp_year => 2018,
    :cvc => "314"
  },
)
=> #<Stripe::Token:0x3fd9c71b002c id=tok_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhSApzxo8u> JSON: {
  "id": "tok_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhSApzxo8u",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {"id":"card_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhBpLf7sFp","object":"card","address_city":null,"address_country":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_line2":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_zip_check":null,"brand":"Visa","country":"US","cvc_check":"unchecked","dynamic_last4":null,"exp_month":1,"exp_year":2018,"fingerprint":"D6Dfg1vPHxjxX2XI","funding":"credit","last4":"4242","metadata":{},"name":null,"tokenization_method":null},
  "client_ip": "31.33.230.61",
  "created": 1485280548,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

but then I'm able to retrieve the token :

```
Stripe::Token.retrieve(tok.id)
=> #<Stripe::Token:0x3fd9c2726b3c id=tok_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhSApzxo8u> JSON: {
  "id": "tok_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhSApzxo8u",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {"id":"card_19fYWGLTk1qRIoGhBpLf7sFp","object":"card","address_city":null,"address_country":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_line2":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_zip_check":null,"brand":"Visa","country":"US","cvc_check":"unchecked","dynamic_last4":null,"exp_month":1,"exp_year":2018,"fingerprint":"D6Dfg1vPHxjxX2XI","funding":"credit","last4":"4242","metadata":{},"name":null,"tokenization_method":null},
  "client_ip": "31.33.230.61",
  "created": 1485280548,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

It simply doesn't work when I pass a customer as a parameter, why? I don't know since I did it because the documentation told me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token was created with the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header, so the resulting token object exists on the destination account.

So in order to [retrieve the token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) or use it in an API request, the request must also use the `Stripe-Account` header with the same account ID.